# Unexpected result when integrating derivative of Dirac function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to compute in Mathematica the following integral:

$$\int_{\rho_0-\epsilon}^{\rho_0+\epsilon} \rho^{-4} \delta'(r-r_0) d\rho,$$
where $\delta$ is the usual dirac delta "function", $\epsilon>0$, and $\rho$ and $r$ are related by $r=1/\rho > 0$.

There are two ways to compute this, integrating with respect to $r$ or $\rho$. I however seem to get two different results when trying both methods:

```
rOf\[Rho][\[Rho]_] = 1/\[Rho];
Assuming[{\[Epsilon] > 0, \[Rho]0 > 0}, 
    Integrate[\[Rho]^(-4) DiracDelta'[rOf\[Rho][\[Rho]] - rOf\[Rho][\[Rho]0]], {\[Rho], \[Rho]0 - \[Epsilon], \[Rho]0 + \[Epsilon]}]]  /. \[Rho]0 -> 1/r0

Assuming[{\[Epsilon] > 0, r0 > 0}, 
    Integrate[-r^2  DiracDelta'[r - r0], {r, r0 - \[Epsilon], r0 + \[Epsilon]}]]
 (* Output:  4r0  and 2r0 *)
```

Upon inspection, it seems like the term you get from the Jacobian when you transform to a new coordinate is not taken into account, or is there a bug in my implementation?

Comment: Both integrals make no sense in traditional math (see https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_functions,_space_of  and https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Delta-function). Simlar questions were asked and answered a lot at this forum.

Comment: There may be a bug in Mathematica. Your first result looks wrong, and the second one looks right.

Comment: @Roman The second Mathematica result gives wrong sign!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes, that is my mistake, because after applying the transformation, the integration should run from $r0+eps$ to $r0-eps$. Switching integration limits then gives an extra minus sign.

Comment: @Patrick.B Fine. Question remains why/where Mathematica fails in your first result!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica sometimes shows problems concerning `DiracDelta'[u]`

As a workaround try

```
dirac = Function[x, Exp[-(x^2/(2 eps))]/Sqrt[2 Pi eps]]
```

as a limiting definition of `DiracDelta[x]=Limit[dirac[x],eps->0]`

```
Assuming[{\[Rho]0 > 0, eps > 0}, 
Integrate[dirac'[ 1/\[Rho] - 1/\[Rho]0]/\[Rho]^4, {\[Rho], \[Rho]0 - Infinity, \[Rho]0 + Infinity}]]

(* -(2/\[Rho]0) *)
```

**addendum**

This analytically result doesn't depend on eps, that's why limit eps->0 can be omitted. This solution agrees with QP's second result except for the sign!

Numerical check shows good agreement  for given parameters `\[Rho]0, eps`:

```
int[\[Rho]0_?NumericQ, eps_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[-((E^(-((1/\[Rho] - 1/\[Rho]0)^2/(2 eps))) (1/\[Rho] -1/\[Rho]0))/(eps^(3/2) Sqrt[2 \[Pi]]))/\[Rho]^4, {\[Rho], \[Rho]0 -
1, \[Rho]0 + 1}] 

Table[\[Rho]0 int[\[Rho]0, .002  ], {\[Rho]0, 1.0, 2.0, .2} ]
(*{-2., -2., -2., -2., -2.0001, -2.00179}*)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: What do you mean by " a limiting definition of `DiracDelta`"? What limit do you have in mind? TIA.

Comment: `Limit[...,eps->0]`

Comment: Up to traditional math, this is the limit in the weak topology, not the usual one.  That notion is not implemented in Mathematica. That was discussed a lot at the forum. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: Sorry, I have no interest   restarting this never-ending discussion about wellknown and accepted properties of `DiracDelta`.

Comment: See the links in my comment to the question for info.